# Как изменить background через события keydown/keypress/keyup?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

```js
function keyDown {
  var bgc = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
  bgc.style.background = "#8ce2bd";
}

function keyUp {
  var bgc = document.getElementByTagName("body");
  bgc.style.background = "#ff6100";
}

function keyPress {
  var bgc = document.getElementsByTagName("body");
  bgc.style.background = "#ff00ee";
}
```

```html
<form oninput="result.value=(t.value)">
  <p>Введите ваш текст:
    <input type="text" name="t" keydown="keyDown()" keypress="keyPress()" keyup="keyUp()"></p>
  <p>Снова он-же: <output name="result"> </output></p>
</form>
```

Comment: если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, [отметьте ответ решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), чтобы он не висел в открытых.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function keyDown() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "#8ce2bd";
}

function keyUp() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "#ff6100";
}

function keyPress() {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.background = "#ff00ee";
}
```

```html
<form oninput="result.value=(t.value)">
  <p>Введите ваш текст:
    <input type="text" name="t" onkeydown="keyDown()" onkeypress="keyPress()" onkeyup="keyUp()"></p>
  <p>Снова он-же: <output name="result"> </output></p>
</form>
```